# Updating child items in List updates all Items in C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Here are my list :

```
public class PayRateDaysModel
{
    public string day_name { get; set; }
    public List<RateList> multiplier { get; set; }
}
public class RateList
{
    public double start_after { get; set; }
    public double rate_multiplier { get; set; }
}
```

when I'm trying to update any value in multiplier of PayRateDaysModel then its updating all multiplier values of PayRateDaysModel. Iw ant to update only current item. Below is my code :

```
var dayExists = daysModel.Where(x => x.day_name == day_name).FirstOrDefault();
if(dayExists==null)
{
    PayRateDaysModel days = new PayRateDaysModel();
    days.day_name = day_name;
    days.multiplier = rate_list;
    daysModel.Add(days);
}
else
{
    //update
    dayExists.day_name = "abc";
    dayExists.multiplier.FirstOrDefault().rate_multiplier = 1;
}
```

Comment: Try `dayExists.multiplier[0].rate_multiplier = 1;`

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: its still updating the rate_multiplier  value of all item present in the PayRateDaysModel

Comment: i want to only update the value of dayExists, but its updating the whole PayRateDaysModel

Comment: I ran code in console application by creating simple classes as you mentioned and it works totally fine!! Can you share mode information what are you doing and how. I suggest you to check process flow one more time.

Comment: Your code will update day_name property and the first item in multiplier of dayExists. Is it you expected?

Comment: This can only happen if the code is running inside a loop and you haven't put a break in the loop so that it doesn't set multipliers' value again if it is set once.

Comment: @mukeshjoshi I have the same problem when i am executing code in loop. Otherwise it  is working fine. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @Tomato32 day_name is updating properly, but for multiplier  it is updating all first element of multiplier in daysModel. But i want to update that in dayExists only.

Comment: @vikrantthakur: Your code just updates first element of multiplier in dayExists. If you need, I can post a sample with output data as your expected. Just use your code, my friend :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have shown to us I would think that you are creating the rate_list somewhere above like `rate_list = new RateList(…)` and you are setting this to all of your days in `days.multiplier = rate_list;`. Since you did not recreate that rate_list for every element, any time you change it in one of your dayExists you will change it for all the others as well.
So you should do something like this `days.multiplier = new RateList(…);`